# How can I setup a fallback registry service for a container image in terraform?

Tags: kubernetes, terraform

quay.io has been down twice this month. https://status.quay.io/

I am looking for a way to fallback to an alternate provider if one service is down.

This is the snippet of the code in question

```
spec {
        service_account_name            = kubernetes_service_account.nginx_ingress.metadata[0].name
        automount_service_account_token = "true"

        container {
          image = "quay.io/kubernetes-ingress-controller/nginx-ingress-controller:${var.nginx_ingress_version}"
          name  = "nginx-ingress-controller"
```

Something like `If quay.io does not return 200, then try other service`